# Lost files while moving through GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, gui

I was moving my files between two folders through GUI. Suddenly the GUI got struck(hanged). So,I closed it. Now I  am unable to find my files. I didn't find any software like remo,minitool(recovery softwares for windows,macOS) for Ubuntu. Any help ?

Comment: did you see your files in the terminal with `ls -l` in src/dst folders?

Comment: Yes I saw both folders(destination and source).

Comment: I don't speak about your folders; for example, your missing file is `toto.txt`, does `ls -l` displays this file in one of your src/dst folders (for example `/home/toto/Downloads` or `/home/toto`)? `ls -l` results is something like *-rw-r--r--  1 toto toto 6746 april  5 09:06 toto.txt*

Comment: No, it is not displaying in both src/dst folders

Comment: and you checked the bin?

Comment: Yes , I checked /bin. I didn't find them

Comment: If you want to play safely, *copy* the files, and check that the copies are there before you remove the files from the original location. You use a command line tool, for example `rsync` (and also in this case, remove the files from the original location, when you know that `rsync` has finished successfully).

Comment: Thank u for suggestion but can you help me to recover my files?

Comment: On what drive were your files? An internal drive or external drive? Maybe you can use PhotoRec according to this link, http://cgsecurity.org

Comment: @MohanAbhyas you can see this link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files